# React useEffect warnings

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component and the following interface

```
interface IProps {
  data: Array<{
    low: number,
    high: number,
    open: number,
    close: number,
    openTime: number
  }>
}


const Canvas: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
 const [data, setData] = useState<Array<{
    low: number,
    high: number,
    open: number,
    close: number,
    openTime: number
  }>>();
}

useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.data)
  }, []) //warning1

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    if (data) {
      setCandleWidth(canvas.width / data.length)
    }
  }, [data && data.length != 0]) //Warning2


}
```

And both useeffects are giving me warnings

The first one is like that because im using it as if it was a componentDidMount() , yet it says

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.data'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setData' needs the
> current value of 'props.data', you can also switch to useReducer
> instead of useState and read 'props.data' in the reducer.

And the second says the following, while i jsut want to trigger it once data is set

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'. Either include
> it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array.
> Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically
> checked.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

What would be a better way to do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, the `useEffect` will only run once, as there's no dependency and you are only initializing the state (you can say) by adding `setData` in `useEffect` with empty array.

You should either add `props.data` in `useEffect` dependency array, or you can directly initialize the data with `useState`.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);

// OR 

useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.data)
}, [props.data])
```

About warning 2:
You are calculating a boolean value in dependency array. This will not trigger the it to re-render. Better add `data` in array and do the checks inside function given by. `useEffect`

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    if (data && data.length != 0 {
      setCandleWidth(canvas.width / data.length)
    }
  }, [data])
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

1. I've dropped the first `useEffect` and passed the data directly to the state.
2. I've edited the dependency array inside the other `useEffect`.

---

```
const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);

useEffect(() => {
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    if (data) {
        setCandleWidth(canvas.width / data.length)
    }
}, [data])
```

Sidenote:

Often times you don't want to duplicate data. `props.data` and `data` (state variable) are holding the same data. If you choose to do this, make sure this is a conscious decision.

Answer (score 1):

this will fix both warnings **without any changes in behavior**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.data)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 }, []) 



 useEffect(() => {
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    if (data) {
      setCandleWidth(canvas.width / data.length)
    }
 }, [data])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `useEffect` is actually fine. It is just an ESLint, TSLint warning - those linters passionately dislikes empty dependency array. If you are **absolutely sure** you want to use an empty array as the dependency array (thus making the effect run only once on initial mount), you can add [ESLint disable as a comment](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) next to the line

As for the second `useEffect`, you are using the dependency array a bit wrong. The dependency array is just for listing dependencies - i.e what React will monitor for changes; it's for listing stuff and should not have logic in it. If you need logic for your conditional rendering, you can put it inside the effect, like @Shreyas Jadhav's answer

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    if (data && data.length != 0) {
      setCandleWidth(canvas.width / data.length)
    }
  }, [data])
```

This second `useEffect` will now mean that, reruns the effect whenever `data` changes, but only `setCandleWidth` if `data.length` is not 0